# Bash find prune isn't working as intended

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have a few git repositories and i want to count how many .txts ,directories and other files they contain.Problem is that inside each repository there is a .git directory containing more files and configurations.I dont want to count either the folder im looking,or the .git directory or its containing files.I use the following command:

```
all="$(find $repo -path "$repo"/.git -prune -o type f)"
dirs="$(find $repo -path "$repo"/.git -prune -o type d)"
txts="$(find $repo -path "$repo"/.git -prune -o type f -iname "*.txt")"
```

`$repo` is the path to my repository and it looks something like `assignments/repo1` `assignments/repo2` etc.
All of these find iterations are still going inside of .git and listing everything there.Am i making a syntax mistake or something?

Comment: Do you mean `$repo` contains two directories?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your responses.I couldnt make `-path` to work so i switched it to `-name`.I also used find in `"$repo"/*` and i think that settled it.I didnt try it but i believe if I used `-path` with `"$repo"/*` it would have worked.